# Writing a program without IF or :? conditional operator

Tags: c

i wanted to write a program which multiplies the second number by 2 if the first one was bigger and divides the first one by 2 if the second one was bigger.is there any other way to do it without loops or :? ?

Comment: use while, sorry but this question is pointless.

Comment: Using `if` or the ternary operator `?` (which compiles down to an `if`) are the only things that I know of.

Comment: just: **why?** Yes, it works for example abusing `while` for an unreadable program. [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_do_while_loop.htm

Comment: Now that you edited your question to "*without loops or :?*", the answer would be "*use `if`*" ...

Comment: There is, but you shouldn't.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a homework puzzle, and I doubt the intent was to use `while` or any other control flow constructs.  They want you to use bitwise operations.  Or, you could use multiply, in fact that may be what they had in mind.  It's simpler.

Comment: if it **is** a "homework puzzle", there's nothing to learn from an answer posted here. Voting to close.

Comment: Here's an approach:  For integers, `a = b > c ? d : e` can be replaced by `t = b > c, a = t*d + (1-t)*e`

Comment: @Tom Karzes you should write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean expression that is convertible to `0` or `1`, and which has no effect when the value is `0`.

> multiplies the second number by 2 if the first one was bigger

```
second = second + (first > second) * second;
```

> and divides the first one by 2 if the second one was bigger.

```
first = first - (second > first) * (first / 2);
```

Comment: i used boolean expression in my code and the program ran successfully.thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem might be solved this way without an if:

```
    int tempA=a;
    int tempB=b; 

    while (a>b){
    tempA=a*2;
    a=b;
}

while(a<b){
    tempA=a/2;
    a=b;
}
     a=tempA;
```